# How to embed an entire azure web site into a WordPress site

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure

I am trying to embed an entire azure website into a wordpress site.  The following works:

```
 <iframe src="https://tvirusly.azurewebsites.net" height="1200" width="1600" title="Covid Risk Calculator"></iframe>
```

but when I click inside the above website or use the following script, it does NOT work:

```
<iframe src="https://tvirusly.azurewebsites.net/AnonymousEvents/Create" height="1200" width="1600" title="Covid Risk Calculator"></iframe>
```

I get the error that tvirusly.azurewebsites.net refused to connect.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the URL https://tvirusly.azurewebsites.net/AnonymousEvents/Create sends the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header. It prevents the site to be included in an iFrame.

If you have access to the source code of tvirusly.azurewebsites.net, then you can see this solution: [Windows Azure iframe domain provider = issue with X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976830/windows-azure-iframe-domain-provider-issue-with-x-frame-options).

You basically set `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` to an empty string.

If you can't change the source, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Roman for that link. That particular solution assumes an App.cs. How would I do this for an MVC ASP.NET azure website where there is no App object? Thanks.

Comment: This was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253840/after-update-to-mvc-5-iframe-no-longer-works). Open Global.asax and add `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
` in `Application_Start()`.

Comment: I don't have a global.asax in my project. it is an ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: Then you are using ASP.NET Core. Global.asax is replaced by Startup.cs in Core. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523565/asp-net-core-x-frame-options-strange-behavior.